# Medical term for the parameters that can be measured in human body

Tags: terminology

How can someone express in a medical term the biological and medical parameters that someone can measure in a human body?

For example I mention just a few like the blood pressure, the glucose level, the heart rate, the cortisol level etc

OP's comment on the suggestion *vital signs*:  *Vital signs* don't include chemical measurements. Usually the vital signs consist of a standard procedure. I would like to know if there is a word or a way to express every measurement such as chemical analysis of blood or analysis for infections.

Comment: @Laurel Vital signs don't include chemical measurements. Usually the vital signs consist of a standard procedure. I would like to know if there is a word or a way to express every measurement such as chemical analysis of blood or analysis for infections etc.. That is how my question is different.

Comment: It may include blood tests: "Other "fifth vital signs" include: ... Blood Glucose level" (Wikipedia). If this is not the answer you're looking for, you should edit your question to add more details.

Comment: I added the OP's comment to his question.  But Laurel still has a point: does the OP mean to include X-rays, MRIs, PET scans, sonograms, or is he excluding these?

Comment: @ab2 The answer I accepted completely covers my question. :)

Comment: I voted to reopen because the "duplicate" has only one answer (vital signs), and the OP of this question explicitly rejected "vital signs" as the answer in the body of his question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about "physiological indicators"?

Also, "biological indicators" may work.  I'm not sure of the total spans of those terms, though

Answer (score 6):

A useful word in this situation is **biometrics**, which can refer to the field of measurement of human biological characteristics, or to the metrics themselves.  However, this might not be the best word for two reasons:

1. It refers to the measurement of things that tend to be stable over time.
2. It is often used an an abbreviation for **biometric authentication**, the use of biometric information to identify people or control access to something.

Comment: "biometric parameters" is possibly less confused with authentication

Answer (score 4):

The term you're looking for is ***vital signs***:

> ***[vital signs](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/vital_signs)***
>
> PLURAL NOUN
>
> Clinical measurements, specifically pulse rate, temperature, respiration rate, and blood pressure, that indicate the state of a patient's essential body functions.
>   *‘check vital signs half-hourly at first’*
>   *figurative ‘students could start coordinated efforts to monitor the earth's vital signs’*

Hope this helps!